# Use service inside service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to add some functionality to Http, when user gets 403 it remove his user information and redirect to login. Example of AuthHttp can be seen below.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttp {
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(url, options)
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
    }

    errorHandler(error: any): Observable<any> {
        if (error.status === 403) {
            console.error('TOKEN EXPIRED!');
            this.authService.logout();

            let link = ['/login'];
            this.router.navigate(link);
        }

        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

The problem is, I will get the following error:

> EXCEPTION: this.authService is undefined

Which I don't know how to get around, since I'm trying to use service inside a service. I added AuthService inside providers like below

```
providers: [ 
    ...,
    AuthService
]
```

Router will throw similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `errorHandler` method, and the context of which `this` refers to. You should bind the function to `this` when you specify it as the callback

```
.catch(this.errorHandler.bind(this));
```

Or if you make `errorHandler` an arrow function, `this` (referring to the service instance) will be maintained

```
errorHandler = (error: any): Observable<any> => {
```

Comment: I thought I made a big mistake somewhere, not just a context issue. Thanks!